# Pascal, merge two text files and sort by line length

Tags: file, sorting, text, pascal

So I have two text files, different lengths, different content. But each line in each file gets bigger/longer with every line.
I need to create a third text file where I will put these lines from both files, also in the same sorting way (beginning with shortest line...).
If both lines in first and second file are the same size I should print them both.

So far I have this:

```
assign(file1, 'file1.txt');
assign(file2, 'file2.txt');
assign(file3, 'file3.txt');
reset(file1);
reset(file2);
rewrite(file3);

readln(file1,s1);
readln(file2,s2);

while MISSING CONDITION do
  begin
    if length(s1) > length(s2) then
    begin
      writeln(file3, s1);
      readln(file1, s1);
    end
    else if length(s1) < length(s2) then
    begin
      writeln(file3, s2);
      readln(file2, s2);
    end
    else
    begin
      writeln(file3, s1);
      writeln(file3, s2);
      readln(file1, s1);
      readln(file2, s2);
    end;
  end;

close(file1);
close(file2);
close(file3);
```

I think my sorting algorithm is fine, if not please correct me. But I need help with the condition for how long I need to do this. I don't know what to do if those two files aren't the same length..

Thank you..

Comment: Well, for one thing, you need to allow for the possibility that ine file has more lines in it than the other.  Along with that, you need to check for the end of each file being reached and adjust your `while` loop to behave correctly once it has.

Comment: You don't tell which Pascal you are using. If it is FreePascal or Delphi, you should consider using TStringLists, to make things a little easier. But only do that if the files are not too big to fit in memory. Otherwise, you should check Eof() for each file individually, and have separate conditions for each possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop reading from a file when you have reached the end of the file. You can detect this with the `Eof()` function. You need to test this condition separately for each input file, as one may hold more lines than the other.

Review your algorithm. If the output file has to go from shorter to longer lines, which line should you write to the file first, the longer or the shorter? ;) Also consider that one file may have several shorter lines before one that is longer than the current line in the other file. You may need to create additional loops inside the main loop.

I suggest you create a couple of test files to test your algorithm.